# Bootstrap Center list when screen size is tablet or mobile sized

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been having trouble and I'm when I searched the web, I couldn't find the solution to this.

I'm currently using bootstrap to create my website, but when I shrink the page down to mobile/tablet-sized, my navbar list shifts to the left. I want it center-aligned, but ONLY when the screen is small. Otherwise, I want my list to be on the right.

I've included a code sample below:

HTML:

```
        <title>ZebarWorld Landing Page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class ="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="LogoPurple.png"></a>
            </div>
            <span class="navbar-text">
                We're currently under construction.<br>Join our waitlist to be the first to play at Zebra World!
            </span>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav myNav">
                <li><a class="navi" href="#">Sign Up for Updates!</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    background-color: #EE870D;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
>}
.navbar{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.navbar-header{
}
.navbar-brand{
}
.navbar-brand img{
    max-width:100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}

.navbar-text{
    text-align:center;
}

.navbar-nav{
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #A12F2F;
    padding: 10px;
}
.myNav{
    text-align: center;
}
.myNav li{
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
a.navi{
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.navi:link{
    color:white;
}
a.navi:visited{
    color: white;
}
a.navi:hover{
    color: black;
}
a.navi:target{
    color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0jpsyot2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use these classes **justify-content-center justify-content-md-between** on container tag

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center justify-content-md-between">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="LogoPurple.png"></a>
            </div>
            <span class="navbar-text">
                We're currently under construction.<br>Join our waitlist to be the first to play at Zebra World!
            </span>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav myNav">
                <li><a class="navi" href="#">Sign Up for Updates!</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: oh! That's what it means. I thought justify-content-center makes everything aggregate in the center. Thanks! I'm learning website making and bootstrap at the same time and a lot of this is making my head go in circles.

Answer (score 0):

By my suggestion you can use the media query in this code

```
@media (max-width: 645px){
  .nav{
   margin-left: 50%;
  }
}
```

in this code i use you nav class and apply media query on this.

or you can also use `justify-content-center` bootstrap class to centralized your button.